# Why is ob_flush() inside drupal_page_footer() causing a 404 and then redirect to same page?

Tags: php, drupal-7, http-status-code-404

I've scoured google and this site but I can't find an answer that applies.

I have inherited a drupal 7 site and all the previous developer's bugs.  On a certain subset of pages I'm seeing the following behavior:

- Navigate to site page
- Get 404 error
- site automatically redirects to the same page
- page loads fine

This happens every time I visit one of these pages.

I've traced through the code locally and tracked that the 404 gets thrown on the ob_flush() command inside the drupal_page_footer() function.  I need direction in what could possibly be causing this behavior and some advice on what steps to take to further track this down.

Comment: Can you post the offending bit of code?

Comment: I suspect the actual bad code exists elsewhere but I don't know why the 404 is thrown right at ob_flush() or where I should look next to debug.  `function drupal_page_footer() {
  global $user;
  module_invoke_all('exit');
  // Commit the user session, if needed.
  drupal_session_commit();
  if (variable_get('cache', 0) && ($cache = drupal_page_set_cache())) {
    drupal_serve_page_from_cache($cache);
  }
  else {
    ob_flush();
  }
  _registry_check_code(REGISTRY_WRITE_LOOKUP_CACHE);
  drupal_cache_system_paths();
  module_implements_write_cache();
  system_run_automated_cron();
}`